# Convert String to Double and check for nil

Tags: arrays, swift, double

I have multiple `Strings` in an array: "1.1", "AA", "1", nil etc... I need to convert the Strings to Double if possible. I have tried this but the code crashes on nil.

```
let doubleValue = Double(array[3]!) // 3 = nil
```

It´s ok if I get nil, at least I know that the value can´t be a Double.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You want array of Double from this string array ?

Comment: If `array[3]` is `nil` then `array[3]!` *crashes.* That has nothing to do with he string to double conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach to do this is to use `map` on `Optional`:

```
let doubleValue = array[3].map(Double.init)
```

In the case that you want to map all of the array to strings, use `map`:

```
let doubles = array.map(Double.init)
```

If you want to filter out all non-double Strings rather than keeping them as `nil`, use `flatMap`:

```
let doubles = array.flatMap(Double.init)
```

Answer (score 2):

It crashes because you are trying to unwrap a nil value. Try giving a default value like this.

```
let doubleValue = Double(test[3] ?? "") 
print(doubleValue) //nil 

let dobuleArray = array.map({ Double($0 ?? "") })
```

Comment: Mapping over the optional is preferable to nil coalescence in this case. It's a more general and more idiomatic solution